# bind a collection view to another view

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, coffeescript

I'm using backbone with the backbone-rails gem which does its own templating and project structure.

The problem is that it puts 4 different views on one div, so what i've done is made another div and now the model, show,edit views are assigned to that other view, basically so i can have a list on the left side of the page and everything else in the middle.

The problem is that i can't redirect now, so when i update or create a new 'note' the list view does not refresh.

List View:

```
  Supernote.Views.Notes ||= {}



  class Supernote.Views.Notes.IndexView extends Backbone.View

  template: JST["backbone/templates/notes/index"]



   initialize: () ->

  @options.notes.bind('reset','change', @addAll)





 addAll: () =>

 @options.notes.each(@addOne)



 addOne: (note) =>

 view = new Supernote.Views.Notes.NoteView({model : note, collection: @options.notes})

  @$("li").append(view.render().el)



 render: =>

 $(@el).html(@template(notes: @options.notes.toJSON() ))

 @addAll()



 return this
```

Edit View:

```
  Supernote.Views.Notes ||= {}



 class Supernote.Views.Notes.EditView extends Backbone.View

  template : JST["backbone/templates/notes/edit"]



 events :

  "submit #edit-note" : "update"



 update : (e) ->

  e.preventDefault()

  e.stopPropagation()



  @model.save(null,

  success : (note) =>

    @model = note

    window.location.hash = "/#{@model.id}"

   )



 render : ->

  $(@el).html(@template(@model.toJSON() ))



 this.$("form").backboneLink(@model)



 return this
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Events is what you need, 
when a model is added to a collection (new note)
it raises the `add` event on the collection itself

so in your collection you can catch that and do something with it.

```
var myCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
   //... whole lot of irrelevant stuff goes here :)
});

var myCollectionListView = Backbone.View.extend({

  initialize: function(){
    _.bindAll(this, 'onAdd');
    this.collection.bind('add', this.onAdd);
  }

  onAdd: function(m){
    // either re-render the whole collection
    this.render();

    // or do something with the single model
    var item = $('<li>' + m.get('property') + '</li>');
    $('#listview').append(item);
  }

});


var myItems = new myCollection({});
var listview = new myCollectionListView({ collection: myItems });
```

then you have the 'add note' covered, (the exact same you could do for the `reset` or `remove` event which handle resetting the collection with a new list of models, and deleting a model from the collection )

let's say you update a note, this should be done with the same event system, though the `change` event could be used for that.
the trick here is, your list view renders not the model elements itself, but the list view creates a modelview for every model. in that modelview (you called it `NoteView`) you could do the same process as above,
and bind to it's own model:

```
initialize: function() {
  this.bind('change', this.modelChanged);
},

modelChanged: function(m){
  // do something, re-render the view, or anything else...
}
```

Comment: thanks for this but isn't the render call for Views only? or are you saying that i instantiate the collection object inside my list view?

Comment: oh i'm sorry you are right, of course it's in the Collection View, that you can bind to the collection.add event with  this.collection.bind()...

Comment: that's awesome thanks for that, worked a treat, so your saying i now need to bind the other actions correct?

Comment: you can bind on any / every collection event yes, add is only 1, you can do remove, reset, as well, find more info on all possible events here: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#FAQ-events

Comment: thanks for your help, you've been awesome. would you know how i go about doing authentication now?

Comment: i've not yet written authentication with backbone, i've done it every time with regular asp or php, and put the backbone app after the login page, authentication that is very secure will be tricky, would not really know how to get started yet... sorry

Comment: i c, i might try and do the same then.

Comment: hey, can one do a shopping cart type app with backbone? so i mean have different models depending on each other, so shopping cart attach to session which is attach to items which are attached to a particular user?

Comment: yes of course you can create a shopping cart with the help of backbone, think of the cart as a collection, collection could be differnt for every user, and the items are the models in the collection.
though how you would be saving that, session, cookie, local storrage, or on the server is up to you of course.

if you have other specific answers please create new questions on stack overflow, as this here (comments on a question) is not the place to discuss unrelated things, so for new questions create a new ticket... more people will be helping then...